# ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT on RDC with smartcard

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2016, smartcard, token

I'm trying to use a smartcard/token connected to my local PC on a remote desktop session. The local machine has Windows 10 and the remote machine has Windows Server 2016.

I installed IDprotect on both machines and configured RDC to allow smartcard passthrough. I installed IDprotect's extra thing for remote during installation.

IDprotect's manager detects the smartcard. But when I try to go into the website for which I need the smartcard - it gives me `ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT`.

Any ideas? I get the errors on Chrome but IE and Firefox don't work either.

Comment: Have you verified the certificate is properly signed?

Comment: You have not supplied the information required to answer this question.  Firefox has it's own certificate store.  it makes sense it would generate an error, unless you also trusted, the root certificate authority that signed the certificate on the card.  Have you done that?  Edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 0):

On Firefox, you need to install a Security device, a PKCS#11 module that supports your smartcard. For example opensc-pkcs11.dll or one provided by your card vendor.

RDP smartcard passthrough support is at the PCSC level. The opensc-pkcs11.so will use PCSC to access the smartcard.

Don't know if IDProtect helps or hurts the situation.